# Resolution of smartphone browsers

Tags: mobile, browser, responsive-design, smartphone

I'm just curious how Android phones specifically calculate the resolution of responsive web pages. For example, I know that while an iPhone 5s has a native resolution of 640x1136, the resolution it uses for webpages is 320x568. (So I can measure the elements of my design accordingly when needed - I typically use percentages, but sometimes I need to measure elements in pixels)

So, when an Android phone visits a responsively designed website, and has a native resolution of 1920x1080, what are the elements on the web page being rendered as in terms of size? Is it also 1/2? Or is it different between devices?

The testing I've done isn't giving me a clear idea of what's happening.

Thanks!

Comment: If you use Chrome, you can use the dev tools device emulator to get the resolution and pixel ratio of different devices. You can also reference this list of displays by pixel density: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density (look in the CSS pixel ratio column)

Comment: @SeanHenderson - this is a wonderful resource that I did not know existed! This really cleared up the mystery for me in how CSS interprets these dimensions. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, most of the time you can get the results you want if you structure everything correctly and just focus on device width.

Device width is a true measure of the pixels on the smartphone or tablet, figures for resolution are typically double for retina devices.

Structuring correctly means:

**(1) In the head of your doc include your meta tag**

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

optionally you could prevent zooming with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```

**(2) In your CSS use media queries like**

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  ...
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  ....
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
  ...
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  ...
}
```

The break points you choose aren't so important but rather the prinicple that you are manipulating the on-screen display based on pixel widths and not complicating your life with pixel ratios, resolution, orientation and other related details.

For sure you will encounter exceptions but if you start simple and it gets the results you want, then you avoid the slippery slope of trying to target devices, and it helps future-proof your design.

Good luck!

Comment: I think you really nailed it when you mentioned that it shouldn't be about the devices necessarily, but the context of the design within the given pixels. Indeed, the breakpoints do not matter, in regards to devices and their resolution. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @alanvitek, I'm pleased this helped clarify things for you

Answer (score 0):

I think it's basically due the aspect ratio of each mobile device than it's resolution. Smartphones are getting "taller" because people want bigger screens, but their hands are not growing, then mobile screens are expandig in height, making viewport width decrease to keep web content confortably readable.

Imagine the width of 1080px of your example, if viewport were equal to device resolution, you will see a website designed for, let's say, a 14 inches notebook in a 6 inches smartphone screen, without mention that you were seeing in portrait, and the notebook is landscape.

I've got the same doubt as you, and find some information here: https://webspeedtools.com/viewport-vs-screen-resolution-vs-dpr-vs-ppi/