# Actual mobile resolution vs css resolution

Tags: html, mobile, responsive-design

I'm developing a mobile app using HTML5 and CSS3 using responsive design. Its quite difficult to find css resolution of mobile.

I'm using Samsugn galaxy Note2. my actual resolution is 1280 X 720. but css resolution is 640 X 360.

How can we calculate css resolution from actual resolution? and what is concept behind this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just relax - don't worry about it, work as if it's 640 x 350, with the only exception being that any images need to be twice the size.

Comment: check out this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24331106/resolution-of-smartphone-browsers/24333789#24333789

Answer (score 1):

You can test for a certain aspect ratio using media queries, however you shouldn't be designing for specific devices or aspect ratios. Responsive design works best when you design for breakpoints as it relates to your content. This way, there's less to worry about, and your content almost always looks better on *every* device